# Flash AS2 - Drag multiple clips simultaneously

Tags: flash, actionscript-2

I have two interface panels on a Flash application. One is the main interface and the other is a configuration panel. The configuration panel is normally invisible, but while visible I would like to have it's position locked to the main interface so they drag at the same time.

The two movieclips are attached like so:

```
var m_Main:MovieClip = attachMovie("MainWindow", "m_Main", getNextHighestDepth());
var m_Settings:MovieClip = attachMovie("SettingsWindow", "m_Settings", getNextHighestDepth());
```

The m_Main clip is draggable and calls these two functions when dragging starts/stops:

```
function StartDrag()
{
  m_Main.startDrag(false, m_Borders.left,m_Borders.top, m_Borders.right, m_Borders.bottom);
  if (m_Settings._visible)
  {
    m_IsDragging = true;
    LocateSettingsWindow();
  }
}
```

and

```
function StopDrag()
{
  m_Main.stopDrag();
  if (m_Settings._visible)
  {
    m_IsDragging = false;
    LocateSettingsWindow();
  }
}
```

LocateSettingsWindow() is:

```
function LocateSettingsWindow()
{
    var position:Point = new Point(m_Main._x, m_Main._y);

    m_Settings._x = position.x - (m_Settings._width + 15);
    m_Settings._y = position.y;

    if (m_IsDragging)
    {
        _global.setTimeout(this, "LocateSettingsWindow", 10);
    }
}
```

Every solution I've found involves something similar to this. Setting an isDragging value to true and then changing the second clips x and y to the first clip. The problem is that in all of the examples I've found, there is some level of delay in moving the second clip so that it seems to lag behind and sort of float loosely around the first clip.

Is there a way to do this so that m_Settings is more solidly locked to m_Main?

Comment: I might try creating a parent movie clip that m_Main and m_Settings are a child to.

Comment: @bigLarry I actually got that same tip from another person a couple of weeks ago. It seems to work exactly as I wanted. Thank you.